# Help with P-channel mosfets

Tags: mosfet

i am trying to get my head around p channel mosfets and bought some A03401 mosfets. As i understand the mosfet will not allow current to flow if Vgs == Vds and thats why the pull up resistor is there. I have not even attempted to connect a microcontroller yet because the led was on in this configuration. i read Vgs and Vds and they are both 0.6v and so i am not sure why the mosfet is allowing current to flow. any help would be much appreciated. thanks.
ps. appolgies for poor picture quality, camera is broken.

[image: circuit]

Comment: It looks like your Source and Drain are swapped. You _are_ talking about a PMOS device, correct? Remember how current flows in a PMOS and NMOS device :)

Comment: If you can't get the connections right at least try and get the part number correct (O not 0).

Comment: ah yes thats the problem thanks! i was still in the mindset of n channel mosfet, you'll have to forgive me i am just a hobbyist. thanks for the help. one last question. would it be safe to switch 4.2v with a 3.3v arduino using this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the P-MOSFET connected wrong. The Source (S) terminal should be toward the 5V and the Drain (D) should connect to the LED in your diagram.

The condition where the P-MOSFET will be off is if the voltage between the Gate (G) and the Source (S) is less than the V<sub>GS<sub>THR</sub></sub>.

The reason that the LED lit up in your drawn configuration is because the body diode was forward biased and letting current pass from the D terminal to the S terminal.